# How many ways we can place 3 balls into 4 boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways we can place 3 balls into 4 boxes. One box may contain more than one balls.

Comment: This is a "Stars and Bars" problem; solution is $(3+4-1)C(4-1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the balls are distinguishable each ball can be placed in any box without restrictions so the number of ways is $4^3$. Why?

If the balls are undistinguishable, use [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: Number of balls are less than the number of boxes. So, there must be empty boxes.

Comment: @user113500 If you hadn't noted I've edited my answer. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Answer. If the balls are different, then there are $4^3$ ways to put them in $4$ boxes.